# Can I use tapestry-jpa with another persistence provider than EclipseLink?

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

I read the Tapestry JPA tutorial at https://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-jpa.html.

1. The persistence.xml that is shown there uses EclipseLink as the implementation. Is it possible to use something else when using tapestry-jpa?
2. I know that I could also use tapestry-hibernate to have Hibernate as the persistence provider. I don't want to be dependent on Hibernate-specific API calls. Does tapestry-hibernate allow that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any JPA2 compatible Provider. Just put it in your classpath and it should work.